# Encode a std::uint64_t into vector of floats

Tags: c++, casting, bit-manipulation

I have to do some dirty trickery and pass a `std::uint64_t` around an application. Unfortunately I am limited to using a `std::vector<float>` for that.

To my understanding `float` is 32-bit on most platforms, so it should be possible to split the 64-bit `std::uint64_t` into two 32-bit ints, represent those as `float` put them in the vector and reverse the process at the other end.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but standard compliant if I'm not mistaken:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
// using assert
#include <cstdint>
// using std::uint64_t
#include <cstring>
// using std::memcpy
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> pack(std::uint64_t value)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(value) >= sizeof(float));
    static_assert(sizeof(value) % sizeof(float) == 0);
    std::vector<float> rtrn(sizeof(value) / sizeof(float));
    std::memcpy(rtrn.data(), &value, sizeof(value));
    return rtrn;
}
std::uint64_t unpack(const std::vector<float>& packed)
{
    std::uint64_t rtrn;
    assert(packed.size() == sizeof(rtrn) / sizeof(float));
    std::memcpy(&rtrn, packed.data(), sizeof(rtrn));
    return rtrn;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

C++23:

```
#include <bit>
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

std::unint64_t ui64{whatever()};
auto vec = std::bit_cast< std::array<float, 2> >(ui64)
         | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

`bit_cast` needs C++20, and `ranges::to` C++23. You can also use traditional `vector::vector(begin, end)` constructor to covert from the array, but `ranges::to` is more readable and less prone to typos.

**Reciprocating routine**:

```
std::vector<float> const flt_vec = {float1(), float2()};
std::array<float,2> flt_arr{};
for(auto&& [a,v] : std::views::zip(flt_arr, vec_arr))
    a=v;
auto ui64 = std::bit_cast<std::uint64_t>(flt_arr);
```

Before trying any of this you can just check if the size of `float` and `uint64_t` match or should use another medium type for `bit_cast`:

```
static_assert(sizeof(std::uint64_t)==sizeof(std::array<float, 2>));
```

Before C++20, `std::memcpy` was the only reliable method of type punning in C++; but this function has well-known pitfalls that discourage its use in user code. For the sake of all related UBs, it cannot be used in compile time evaluated context either. Therefore C++20 has introduced `std::bit_cast` as a `constexpr` reliable compiler magic for type-punning on trivial types.  If `sizeof` source and destination are equal, then this function returns a value of destination type with exact same bit pattern as the source object.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the C++23 way! Unfortunatelly the compiler we use is still on C++17... But I will remember it for the future :)